# Unable to build selenium script in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Unable to build  Selenium Script in Jenkins.

Generating error related to Browser driver.

**Working Code in Eclipse with Maven**

```html
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class NewTest {
    private WebDriver driver;  
  @Test    
  public void testEasy() throws InterruptedException { 
   System.out.println("Testing");
  driver.get("http://www.google.com/");  
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  String title = driver.getTitle();     
  
  } 
 
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() throws MalformedURLException { 
   System.out.println("@BeforeTest");
  //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Selenium\\Selenium Library\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
 
   //Now you can Initialize marionette driver to launch firefox
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
  
     
   /*FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
          .addPreference("browser.startup.page", 1)
          .addPreference("browser.startup.homepage", "http://demo.guru99.com/test/guru99home/");
         driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
         */
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }  
  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
   System.out.println("@@AfterTest");
  driver.quit();
  }

}
```

After trying to run POM.xml build in Jenkins. It's result failed because of Unable to execute gecko driver.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKgL7.png)

```html
Failed
test.NewTest.beforeTest (from TestSuite)

Failing for the past 26 builds (Since Unstable#11 )
Took 1.2 sec.


add description

Error Message

The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Stacktrace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
 at test.NewTest.beforeTest(NewTest.java:39)
Standard Output

@BeforeTest
Standard Error
Apr 20, 2018 2:12:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
```

Any one have idea about how to resolved this issue please provide me solution for that

Comment: This usually occurs when you give incorrect driver type. For example,. you are working on win machine and then you pass driver compatible with mac. Can you confirm you are executing case on same machine (with or without Jenkins)?

Comment: I already verified the driver type and it's perfect. And above code is perfectly working in same machine without jenkins.

Comment: Let me try your code.

Comment: Your geckodriver system property code is commented and the path doesn't seem to be correct. This error comes when the driver executable is not found to be executed for the remote command execution.

Comment: I have already Set geckodriver system property path in Environment Variable and i have already check by un-commented path. same issue accruing..